# Display Markers Android Google Maps api

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, maps, google-maps-markers

I'm new with Google Maps Android API. I know this question has already been posted but they're old and I'm referring to the new API version.
I'm developing a Navigation Drawer having one of the fragment dedicated to Maps.
I can only see Maps but with no Markers, no zoom. sounds like Maps wouldn't be properly loaded.

public class MapsFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback{

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_maps, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    MapFragment mapFragment =  (MapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(44.797283, 20.460663);
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
```

This is the xml called fragment_maps.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.app.myapp.view.MapsFragment">

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please don't take shortcuts from the samples.  Save the GoogleMap object then use the properties and methods of the saved object.

```
   @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            mMap = googleMap;

            // Add a marker in Sydney, Australia, and move the camera.
            LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
        }
```

Comment: Unfortunately creating a private GoogleMap object and assigning it to the method argument doesn't solve the issue. I debugged it and I noticed it never get into the onMapReady method: something else stops the map loading.
Maps are displaying correctly so the API key is right.
I'd think the issue is related to the Fragment and the Navigation Drawer

Comment: it might be mapFragment.getMapAsync(this.onMapReady)  IDK I'm not at the IDE now.